# How to customize description in the event autocomplete in Register New Participant Page dynamically?

Tags: autocomplete, civicrm-event

I need to add remaining seats available in the description seen in the event autocomplete along with some custom data based on domain,how can I customize it?
[image]

I was looking into this code below to see if that can help to fix but unable to get further on it.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.7.14/api/v3/Generic/Getlist.php#L159

```
function _civicrm_api3_generic_getlist_postprocess($result, $request, &$values) {
  $chains = array();
  foreach ($request['params'] as $field => $param) {
    if (substr($field, 0, 4) === 'api.') {
      $chains[] = $field;
    }
  }
  if (!empty($result['values'])) {
    foreach (array_values($result['values']) as $num => $row) {
      foreach ($request['extra'] as $field) {
        $values[$num]['extra'][$field] = isset($row[$field]) ? $row[$field] : NULL;
      }
      foreach ($chains as $chain) {
        $values[$num][$chain] = isset($row[$chain]) ? $row[$chain] : NULL;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the autocomplete url used is

> civicrm/ajax/rest?entity=event&action=getlist

Comment: If you're going to do any development on this make sure you use the latest version.  4.7.14 is old.